# Request from the database during activity creation

Tags: android

How to output data from the database during the creation of an activity or fragment? I get the data myself using ROOM, but they naturally come later than the activity is created. How do I add an execution wait with a progress bar? How to do this at the click of a button I know the problem is when creating a fragment or activity. Partially solved the problem with the transmission of already pre-received data through arguments according to the scheme: When creating a fragment, I create an object of the Repository->class by clicking the button, I get the data and pass it through arguments to another fragment. I am interested in how to make the activity wait for the data, show the progress bar, and update the UI when they arrive.

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                AppDataBase db = App.getInstance().getAppDataBase();
                PersonDao personDao = db.personDao();
                db.personDao().getAll()
                        .subscribeOn(io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new Consumer<List<EntytiList>>() {
                                @Override
                                public void accept(List<EntytiList> entytiLists) throws Exception {
                                        mEntytiLists = entytiLists;
                                        System.out.println(mEntytiLists+" update");
                                }
                        });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post in English.

Comment: Please change the title also to English.